# can't enable scroll behaviour of webview when hiding toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-coordinatorlayout

So far with my code below I am able to hide the toolbar when scrolling a webview upwards and showing the toolbar when the web view is scrolled downwards but with this implementation  below I have lost the scrolling behavior of the webview itself

this is my app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity">
    <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="true"-->


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is the news.xml that I use in my fragment . My problem here is if I remove the NestedScrollView I am able to scroll the webview & do the swipe to refresh function but when I add the Nested view I can scroll the toolbar up & down but the scrolling property of the webview & swipe to refresh is lost

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
        >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/website_detail_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            </WebView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragment that contains the webview

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {



    // private String url;
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar1;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout1;

    public NewsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static NewsFragment newInstance(String webUrl) {
        //set arguments
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("website", webUrl);
        NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();

        newsFragment.setArguments(args);

        return newsFragment;

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);


    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //get back arguments
        final String url = this.getArguments().getString("website");


        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.website_detail_1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);




        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                progressBar1.setProgress(progress);

                if (progress == 100) {

                    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout1.isRefreshing()) {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }


        });


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });


        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        //   webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) { // loading offline
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        }


        webView.loadUrl(url);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout1 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe1);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });

        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its more complicated that I thought but this repository helped me thru

```
<yourpackage.name.NestedWebView 
    android:id="@id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/takahirom/webview_in_coodinator_layout/NestedWebView.java

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the positions of the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and the `NestedScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/website_detail_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

- Take `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` off the `NestedScrollView` (leave it on the `ViewPager`, that's all you need to make it work)
- Change the height of your `WebView` to `wrap_content`.  You will probably need to do this with the `SwipeRefreshLayout` as well.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but it didn't have any effect at all. my webview is WebChromeClient. I have not set any properties about scrolling its there by default. I am also using a Navigation drawer does it have to do anything ?

Comment: the swipe to refresh finally works with the code however I am not able to scroll the webview as the layout apparently makes the scrolling of the webview fixed. I can now hide and show toolbar /refresh my webview but no horizontal scrolling.  I have updated my fragment that contains the webview if it would help ?